# Responsive Javascript/jQuery image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, mobile, responsive-design

I'm desperately searching for a simple, usable and **responsible** (usable on mobile websites) image gallery written in Javascript, jQuery the best. My requirements:

- gallery type **like lightbox**, fancybox, etc. (clicking on a link bring the big linked image/content on screen and darkens the rest)
- NOT carusel, slideshow etc.
- grouping
- **usable on mobile devices** with small screen - mobile Safari, Chrome, Opera (in many galleries, a big image doesn't scale down and center on screen), so:

  - big and visible control buttons or swipe funcionality
  - small borders so the image fills a lot of screen
  - speed
- title visible

I don't need any fancy transitions etc. It's nice to have but not if any of the requirements above wouldn't be met.

Quite outstanding solution is here: http://www.tuzemska-dovolena.cz/ubytovani/jizni-cechy/penzion-thalleruv-dum/. Looks like modified fancybox, but I don't want to steal it.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Honestly, I've searched far and wide for these things and I just wasn't impressed with what is out there.  Most of the jQuery based image galleries aren't very customizable and a lot of them are poorly written. In my experience it is best to roll your own if you need something very specific (which it seems like you do).  As far as the mobile version, you'd probably have to have two separate scripts, one for desktop and one for mobile.

Comment: Fancybox without configuration is not usable on mobile phones because:
1. due to it's fixed margins from browser's borders, it fills approx 80% width of browser's width, so it actually makes the poped image smaller 
2. left/right controls are not visible
3. Box with title breakes when it doesn't fit in a single line
Otherwise it works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been doing a little searching as well and came across a couple that may meet your criteria:

1. [Photo Swipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/)
2. [jQuery Responsive Thumbnail Gallery Plugin](http://johnpolacek.github.com/ResponsiveThumbnailGallery/)

Comment: The jQuery plugin link gives a 404 now, fyi.  Is photo swipe the best option, do you think?